# Why does Pandas str.fullmatch blank values default to else?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string

Let's say we have a dataframe col df['Old'] that looks like this

```
0        NaN
1        NEWARK, NJ
```

And we apply this to fill out the values of a new col

```
df['New']=np.where(df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...')==False,'Value','Else Value')
```

The result is

```
0       Else Value
1       Else Value
```

This makes sense for the second row, since the regex matches therefore the fullmatch evaluates to True and so we return the else value. But for the NaN, why is it also returning the else value? The NaN regex does not match so shouldn't the fullmatch evaluate to False and return Value?

Comment: @JohnGordon When you compare a series to a scalar it performs element-wise comparison.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  I really should just stop trying to answer pandas questions...

Comment: Is `NJ` the end of the column value in the second row?  Or is there perhaps a trailing space?

Comment: @JohnGordon the issue is with the NaN, the second row has an expected behavior

Comment: This is not "Python str.fullmatch" (that would mean "the `fullmatch` method of ordinary strings" - there is no such thing), but "Pandas DataFrame.str.fullmatch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...')` returns `NaN` for the first value and `NaN == False` is `False`

Reproducible example with intermediates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Old': [float('nan'), 'NEWARK, NJ']})

df['match'] = df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...')
df['match==False'] = df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...') == False
df['New'] = np.where(df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...') == False,
                     'Value', 'Else Value')
```

Output:

```
          Old match  match==False         New
0         NaN   NaN         False  Else Value
1  NEWARK, NJ  True         False  Else Value
```

Workaround: first [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with an empty string:

```
df['New'] = np.where(df['Old'].fillna('').str.fullmatch('.*,...') == False,
                     'Value', 'Else Value')
```

Or with the boolean NOT (`~`):

```
df['New'] = np.where(~df['Old'].fillna('').str.fullmatch('.*,...'),
                     'Value', 'Else Value')
```

Or reversing the values:

```
df['New'] = np.where(df['Old'].fillna('').str.fullmatch('.*,...'),
                     'Else Value', 'Value')
```

Output:

```
          Old         New
0         NaN       Value
1  NEWARK, NJ  Else Value
```

Comment: You can demonstrate this with `print(df['Old'].str.fullmatch('.*,...'))`

Comment: @Barmar I added the intermediates for clarity ;)